# Typescript: typings for exporting an object

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I have a maddeningly trivial scenario I just can't crack with Typescript. I have an es6 module exporting a simple object:

```js
// variables.ts
export default {
   one: 1,
   two: 2
}
```

I want to import it like so:

```js
import vars from './path/to/variables.ts';
```

But when I try to reference `vars.one` I get an error in my IDE: "Property 'one' does not exist on type 'typeof import(...)'".

I've tried several workarounds like creating a typings file with the object definition, defining an interface in the file (and exporting it as a named var) but no luck.

Comment: If you hover over `vars`, what does the IDE tell you the type is?

Comment: Nothing, oddly (no intellisense tooltip - I'm using WebStorm btw). Only when I mouseover `one` in `vars.one` does the intellisense tooltip show the error I listed.

Answer (score 1):

Apologies, this was caused by a tsconfig setting. I was explicitly omitting the file I was trying to import through the "exclude" option in that file. Removing that solved the issue.